How to boot my Samsung Phone to Recovery without cable attached?
I have a Samsung Galaxy A52S 5G, and I can't figure out how to reliably boot to recovery. It works most of the time when I have the cable plugged in to my PC, and Samsung moderator StephK1 has stated

Officially, our guide only states that USB-C headphones and connecting to a PC will work

Well, I don't usually carry my desktop PC with me, and having to get the laptop or headphones out is silly too. I have an unlocked bootloader and root (on lineage OS), so I have hopes that there's a way to change this.
For example, on my previous phone I could boot to recovery (e.g. TWRP) with Power + VolumeUp held for a few seconds, starting from powered off state.
How can I tweak my phone to do this?

Sidenote: I am aware that there are apps that make reboot into recovery possible. I am specifically hoping for a way to do this from poweroff state. Useful for example in the common case of randomly bootlooping and not wanting to wait for recovery to come by itself.
Sidenote 2: Apparently, one can even connect to another phone, to allow booting to recovery.
